# I am just try to print factorial of the given number to next activity and got error

Tags: android

I know here many silly mistake I made.. But I am beginner and try to learn it step by step.. Please help me to solve this:)

This is my MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.practical6;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  View.OnClickListener{

    EditText e1;
    Button b;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        e1=findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName);
        b=findViewById(R.id.button);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Integer number= Integer.valueOf(e1.getText().toString());
        Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity2.class);
        i.putExtra("user",number);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

This is my MainActivity2.java

```
package com.example.practical6;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
   TextView t;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        t=findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        Intent i2 = getIntent();
        Integer number= (i2.getIntExtra("user",0));
        int x=number;
        for(int i=1; i<x; i++)
        {
            x =(x*i);
            t.setText(x);
        }
    }
}
```

It gives error like:-

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.practical6/com.example.practical6.MainActivity2}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x6
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)

**Code ran in emulator activity 1 will be shown I entered number press the button for submit and then It'll give me error that practical has been stopped unfortunately..**

Comment: please add the error to your question. if you are already a beginner you should use Kotlin Instead of java and Jetpack compose for UI

Comment: Add error to find out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Mistake is in this line,

```
    x =(x*i);
```

When loop is iterating value of 'x' will be keep multiplied and it will always be greater than 'i' so condition that you put in for loop 'i<x' will always be true.

For that reason, loop will run for infinite times and your app will crash.

Solution:

```
Instead of this:
        x =(x*i);
        t.setText(x);
Just Use this:
        t.setText(x*i)
```